# Create a standalone GUI application compatible with windows 7

Tags: windows, python, .net, mysql

I want to create a standalone GUI application compatible with windows 7 and through which pre-created database accession will be easier. I know to create these kind of application VB.NET is used, where C# language is used. I want to create this application using python, is it possible? If, it is possible then please let me know the software, where to make it.

Comment: please answer my question. It is very important for me

Comment: Yes, it is possible. For GUI, see https://wxpython.org/. For database ... you didn't tell us which one